# AngularJS: Cant fetch any data from rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, single-page-application

I made this small API on rails with a single resource called Items, that works fine while I use it on the browser (a.k.a http://localhost:9000/api/items/1.js - Configured port 9000 with Grunt proxy), but when I try to get that data from Angular I get nothing.

//app.js

```
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/items', {
        templateUrl: 'views/items.html',
        controller: 'ItemsCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
app.factory('Item', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  return $resource('http://localhost:9000/api/items/:id.json', null, {
    'update': { method:'PUT' }
  });
}]);
```

//items.js

```
angular.module('balenciagaApp')
  .controller('ItemsCtrl', ['$scope', 'Item', function ($scope, Item) {
    $scope.items = Item.query();
  }]);
```

//items.html

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in items">
  <li>{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you have any error in your console? Is the HTTP request made (see it in the network info in dev tools)? If yes, what is the data returned?

Comment: Thanks for your response, had to go afk. Will check when I get back.